# Whats the best way to convert a contractor's rate to an employee's rate

Tags: salary, contractor

Whats the best way to convert a contractor's rate  to an employee's rate

Answer (score 0):

You have to estimate based on several criteria:

Employment taxes for an employee are around 15% of wages. Add in the cost of any benefits like paid time off, holiday pay, plus any added costs around equipment, computers, supplies, extra coffee, etc. As a rule of thumb, an employee is 25% more on the low end, and even as high as 40% or more on the high end.

In other words, if you are considering hiring a former contractor as a full time employee, knocking ~25% off his contractor rate is reasonable, and there is room to negotiate based on the benefits you offer.

Comment: Math addendum: I realize 25% off the higher value is not the same amount as 25% more than the lower value, please calculate accordingly.